# How to convert old PEF pentax raw format to jpg or mp4?

Tags: video-conversion, format, mp4, jpeg

I have some old pentax .PEF files and I want to convert it updated jpg or mp4 formats. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can open the Pentax electronic files with Adobe Photoshop (and then save them how you wish) or use an online service to convert the files to JPG.

Comment: this is a image format right? not a video format?

Comment: If the file is a movie I am not sure how to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

### Imagemagick's convert should be able to do the work

### Convert bild.pef bild.png

Answer (score 0):

There are two self-contained applications that should be able to convert Pentax Electronic File (PEF) to other formats. Regrettably, both are general-purpose, *large* downloads, but both are quire useful.

- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) is a free image editing tool. Use [a script](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/18692743) to convert to TIFF format, and from that format, almost any tool, such as [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/), should be able to convert to another format.
- Nikon's [free NX Studio](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/sw/195.html) has an *immense* database of file formats and lens corrections.
- A third choice is an online service, such as [Zamar's PEF converter](https://www.zamzar.com/converters/image/pef/), with the *caveat* that you're giving a third party access to the image.